# React Native animated : scale is not defined error

Tags: react-native, animation

Im facing this error :

ReferenceError: scale is not defined

4 |
5 |
6 | const Revue = () => {

> 7 |   scale = new Animated.Value(1)
> 8 |
> 9 |   onPinchEvent = Animated.event(
> 10 |     [

---

This is my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { PinchGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
 

const Revue = () => {
  scale = new Animated.Value(1)

  onPinchEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: { scale: this.scale }
      }
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true
    }
  )

  onPinchStateChange = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      Animated.spring(this.scale, {
        toValue: 1,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }).start()
    }
  }

  return (
    <PinchGestureHandler
      onGestureEvent={this.onPinchEvent}
      onHandlerStateChange={this.onPinchStateChange}>
      <Animated.Image 
        source={require('../images/revue/01.jpg')}
        style={{
          width: screen.width,
          height: 300,
          transform: [{ scale: this.scale }]
        }}
        resizeMode='contain'
      />
    </PinchGestureHandler>
  )
}

export default Revue
```

thank you in advance

Comment: It should be `const scale = new Animated.Value(1)`, you have missed defining the variable.
Furthermore, it is wiser to use `const scale = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current` to persist the scale value across re-renders if any.

Comment: thank you for your quick help but another error showed : TypeError: Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined
   9 | onPinchEvent = Animated.event(
  10 |   [
  11 |     {
> 12 |       nativeEvent: { scale: this.scale }
     | ^  13 |     }
  14 |   ],

Comment: You should be using just `scale` not `this.scale`. Since you're using a function not a class.

Comment: thank you a lot   Prãtéék Thápá